# Pattern matching on binary type cannot use the value of a variable

Tags: erlang, elixir

E.g:

```
arg = "echo:hello"
prefix = "echo"

case arg do
  <<^prefix, ":", msg::binary>> -> IO.puts("Echo message: #{msg}")
  _ -> IO.puts("No match")
end
```

Result: `No match`

What if I want to use the value of `prefix` as a pattern match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't work because you can only match fixed size binaries if you're not matching the "rest" of the string. There are 3 different solutions, depending on your use-case

#### 1. Calculate the size beforehand

If you really want to use that binary pattern matching, you can manually calculate the size beforehand:

```
arg = "echo:hello"
prefix = "echo"
prefix_size = byte_size(prefix)

case arg do
  <<^prefix::binary-size(prefix_size), ":", msg::binary>> -> IO.puts("Echo message: #{msg}")
  _ -> IO.puts("No match")
end
```

#### 2. Use compile-time module attributes

Depending on your use case, you could use module attributes, which size is known at compile time so they do work:

```
defmodule MyModule do

  @prefix "echo"

  def test(arg) do
    case arg do
      <<@prefix::binary, ":", msg::binary>> -> IO.puts("Echo message: #{msg}")
      _ -> IO.puts("No match")
    end
  end
end
```

#### 3. Use String.replace_prefix/3

Or, if you want to keep `prefix` a runtime binary, you could use `String.replace_prefix/3`

```
arg = "echo:hello"
prefix = "echo"

case String.replace_prefix(arg, "#{prefix}:", "")do
  ^arg -> IO.puts("No match")
  msg -> IO.puts("Echo match: #{msg}") 
end
```

`String.replace_prefix/3` returns the input string if there is no match found, so we match it via `^arg`. If this is not the case, we got a match and since we replaced the prefix with `""`, we just get the part after the `:`.

Comment: In second example in `@prefix::binary` the `::binary` part is redundant: module attributes are expanded by compiler and `@prefix` will work as `":"` works.